# JavaScript from .js.erb is executed but is also displayed as text

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, popupwindow

I have a form in a popup window like this:

```
<%= form_tag "/controller/action", :method => :get, :remote => true do %>
...
<% end %>
```

In my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

After submitting I am trying to change elements of parent window in `action.js.erb`:

```
window.opener.$('#some-div').html('<div class="flash notice">...</div>');
```

Or without jQuery:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('some-div').innerHTML = '<div class="flash notice">...</div>';
```

In both cases I get the flash message in my div as I wanted plus the whole content of action.js.erb as text.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that Rails is escaping your text.